# How do i print a addition inside a string

Tags: python

im brand new to programming and after a couple of youtube videos i decided id try to do a new program, after all the only real way of learning something is by practicing it

```
n = input ("Name :")
i = input ("Age :")
aa = input ("How many years do you wish ( 0 to 99) :")

print("Mr." + n + " in the year 20" + aa + "will have" + i + aa)
```

Heres my code, i wanted to add i+aa so it would tell me the final age, but instead it just adds them like 2 strings, thanks!

Comment: That's because they are strings! You need to convert to integers using `int` and then add. You can convert back to a string using `str`

Comment: After you have actual ints, you'll probably need to do `"will have" + (i + aa))`

Comment: Also, think about when `aa < 10`. What year will be printed?

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example of the code converted into strings? Thanks!